# Error installing "nokogiri" in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I've been following along with the Lynda.com's Ruby on Rails course. I did everything just as mentioned inside the videos.

I am trying to run the `rails server` command, which should default to WEBrick, correct?

I run the command and it has an issue in the `nokogiri.rb` file and on line 29 where the error is happening this is what is read:

```
require 'nokogiri/nokogiri'
```

Which is what my command prompt is throwing up on when running the `rails server` command. Any idea what could be causing this? If so, what commands do I need to run to settle this? To me it sounds like something was missed when installing MySQL.

I am not sure what `nokogiri` is and why `rails server` won't run and points to that line of code.

The path to this file is `(Wherever you installed the folder to)\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32\lib`

EDIT**: I have a chain of errors, like it goes from -long path-, from -longpath- etcetera. I tried installing the latest gem, and it wasn't successful. Is there a log file I can get to share with you guys to help figure out the issue.

Comment: When you run into an error message, you should post the *entire* error message. Bear in mind that we're not in the room with you, looking over your shoulder.

Comment: can u  share your error log what u got while running rails server ?

Comment: I don't know how to copy the error message from the command prompt. Is there some place that I can get a log file?

Comment: Try looking in `logs/development.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.6.6.2) is a Ruby "gem" (library) for parsing XML and HTML.

Your Rails project should have a Gemfile which specifies the name and version of each gem needed to run the project.  To install the gems listed in the gemfile:

```
bundle install
```

After that install completes successfully, Rails should be able to find the nokogiri gem.

Comment: I tried a bundle install. nokogiri is on the list, but when I try to run the rails server command, it still does not work.

Comment: @destructi6n I was under the impression that my answer didn't solve your problem...  just so you know, you don't have to award the checkmark "just because".  It's OK to leave no answer with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32\lib`, which means that you are running it on Windows platform. You are using `ruby 2.2.0`.

I know that `nokogiri` conflicts with `2.2.*` versions of ruby in Windows. I have already encountered this problem. I think it is because of `mingw32`.

You need to install `2.1.*` version of Ruby in order to make Nokogiri work.