# Uninstalling Ruby to go to an older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, nokogiri, uninstallation

I'm trying to learn Ruby On Rails, and found I can't really use Ruby 2.2.2 because Nokogiri doesn't support it on Windows yet.

How do I roll back Ruby to an older version so I can develop on an older framework while I wait for Nokogiri to come up with a product for Windows and Ruby 2.2.2?

What is the best way to uninstall it so I don't have bits hanging around that might cause issues?

This is in response to my question: "[Error installing "nokogiri" in a Ruby on Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036630/error-installing-nokogiri-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application/32043063#32043063)"

Comment: Well, if you really want good suggestion: move to Linux (or Mac, for that matter). I was using Ruby/Rails on Windows for a year or so, and I felt the suffering had ended when I moved away from Windows. Gem-makers usually don't really give a heck about Windows users.

Comment: Will any Linux distro be sufficient? i.e Ubuntu? Not entirely sure about moving to Linux and Mac laptops are very expensive and over priced.

Comment: How did you install it on windows in the first place? Does that have an uninstaller?   As long as the install dir isn't in your path, any of the bits laying around shouldn't matter.   Building a dev vm, is an option, buying  mac is an option.  But using something like railsinstaller and installing into a new directory should get you moving forward.. Just remember that most everything /tutorials etc. seem to assume a *nix like environment.

Comment: The only real hesitation I hesitate from Linux itself is because I also play games on my personal computer and as far as I know Linux isn't fairly treated for video games. It's looking more and more like I'm going to need to get a mac laptop.

Comment: No you don't need a Mac Laptop (But they are very nice, LOL). You can install linux in a virtual machine (virtualbox is free), and just use it for Dev. etc. And not have to worry about not being able to play games in linux, etc...

Comment: I agree that they are nice, but I would be very mad spending the amount of money they want for them. $2,400 dollars is unacceptable for a 128gb ssd for storage, and an i5.

Comment: @destructi6n Install Linux on Virtual machine, I support that advice. VirtualBox is free, and you can download some ready-to-use virtual image (or install Ubuntu from scratch). When you are ready, you can move it to the real partition of your hard drive (leaving Windows on separate partition for games).

Comment: If you're on windows 7 [Wubi installer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards) might still be an option too. [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) Otherwise use VirtualBox to create a VM or setup a Dual Boot. IMO its a sucky answer (just use linux) but unfortunately you'll be jumping through so many unnecessary hoops to satisfy the windows use case. Also My 2 cents on a good intro Linux Distro is Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu)

Comment: Definitely a Linux distro or a Mac is best for development. I recommend Linux Mint or Ubuntu to start with as those are heavily supported. You can either VirtualBox or Dual Boot. If you don't have much RAM, you may want to Dual Boot since running two OSes at once (with VirtualBox) may cause a little lag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Linux users:*** please remember that not everyone is interested in switching their OS, running 2 machines, trying to figure out dual boot, or dealing with virtual machines dragging down a host. While Linux is a great environment for software development, people, like the OP, just looking to try their hand at something (like ruby/rails) should not immediately be told to switch to something completely unfamiliar which might not even adequately support their normal day to day activities.

Since I am not a believer in making anyone leave an environment they are comfortable with (especially since you stated *"learning"*. Why would you want to make an additional investment just to try something out?) and because I did not want my comment to get over looked as it will help with your issue, I have decided to post this as an "answer".

Mac and Other *nix based OS's have the ability to install [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) (Yes I know there are more but `rvm` is my personal choice and a community favorite) which allows you to manage different versions of ruby on the same OS.

While `rvm` is not available for Windows there is a small application called [`uru`](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru) which will get you as close from a windows standpoint.

Installing a version manager means that you do not need to uninstall or rollback anything you can simply install a new/old ruby version side by side the current versions you have and switch between them fairly easily from command line.

While `uru` does not have all the fancy features that other applications like `rvm` possess (by design). It contains the important ones (primarily in your case switching ruby versions). The CLI is very simple and straight forward. [Examples of uru Usage](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/wiki/Examples)

**Also**: Please note I work in an Windows centric Office and have developed more than a few fully functional rails applications on a windows machine. Yes there are some headaches when dealing with native extensions and know that you will always be slightly behind the leading edge for ruby and rails but it is completely possible and feasible to build enterprise level web applications completely in a Windows environment without ever installing Linux at all. (Note I do use dedicated Linux machines for non development web servers)

Comment: I've done it this way too, the problem is you'll have lots of issues when it's time to deploy in a different environment. If you're just tinkering this may be the way to go, but if you eventually want to be able to deploy your rails app on Linux, your best bet really is Vagrant (Virtualbox).

Comment: @pguardiario not sure I understand I have have never had any issues deploying from windows to linux for a rails application. Ruby is ruby regardless of the operating system, as long as the ruby and gem versions match it will function the same across all platforms. Also I am not sure what vagrant really has to do with this at all. If you really want to avoid any headaches why would you want to code a machine when you could simply take a physical machine and build it to spec or atleast use a VM with a bit more stability than VirtualBox like vmware or microsoft *Yes HyperV supports linux builds

Comment: I'm talking about issues with dependencies (like what the poster is experiencing with Nokogiri). If you've never experienced these you've been very lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your control panel and find the ruby or rails installer. Uninstall it. Go to your file explorer and make sure the folder is gone.

Now go to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and pick an older version. Follow that process just like the first time you installed ruby. Then go get nokogiri and whatever other gems you like and enjoy.

I had the exact same issue when trying to some gems(stanford core nlp & treat) to work that relied on JVM that was 32bit instead of 64 like the version of ruby I was running so I reverted to 1.9.3.

I'm also in the avoiding moving to OSX or linux camp so I feel your pain man.

Let me know if this works and good luck!

Comment: Someone who understands :D. I'm gonna give throwing linux into a VM, just so I can enjoy the latest version of Ruby and rails 4. If not then that will be my last step. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Let me know how it goes! If it's painless maybe I'll join you.